# Категории item'ов внутри Recyclerview

Tags: android, recyclerview, cardview

Делаю приложение Todolist, есть список заметок. Заметки выводятся в RecyclerView, Cardview.
Встал вопрос как разбить эти заметки по категориям на основании приоритета заметки.
На гитхабе нашел следующий разбор:
[SimpleSectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/4c189fb1124df4556058)

Если разбить заметки на секции по этому методу, будет ли возможность при дальнейшем конструировании приложения сделать так, что при перетаскивании заметок в другую категорию (зажимаем заметку и переносим) заметка будет попадать в другую категорию? Или для этого необходимо использовать другую схему реализации категорий?
Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: вы хотите просто сортировку по важности с выделением допустим цветом?

Comment: Не просто сортировку, а чтобы именно были категории сверху заметок. И перемещая зЗаметку,она попадала в другую категорию

Comment: а вариант с несколькими Recyclerview по количеству категорий?

Comment: А способ с несколькими recyclerView не является плохим решением которое нагружает приложение?  Получается если несколько recyclerview сделать и разбить на мкатегори, можно item перетаскивать из одного recyclerView  в другой?

Comment: Не нагрузит, дело вкуса. Перетаскивание в разные Recyclerview не делал

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, может кто нибудь еще подскажет, потому что главное условие для категорий, чтобы можно было перетаскивать между категориями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы решил задачу следующим образом.

[image: ezgif-com-gif-maker-3.gif]

`Activity`:

```
class TodoSortActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var touchHelper: ItemTouchHelper
private lateinit var viewModel: TodoSortViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_todo_sort)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TodoSortViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.items.observe(this) {
        val adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter(it, { holder ->
            touchHelper.startDrag(holder)
        }, { item ->
            // обработать перетаскивание
        })
        recycler_view.adapter = adapter

        val callback: ItemTouchHelper.Callback = ItemMoveCallback(adapter)
        touchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(callback)
        touchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recycler_view)
    }
}
}
```

`Adapter`:

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter(
data: List<TodoItem>,
private val dragListener: (RecyclerView.ViewHolder) -> Unit,
private val changePositionListener: (TodoItem) -> Unit,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(), ItemTouchHelperContract {

companion object {
    private const val TYPE_ITEM = 0
    private const val TYPE_HEADER = 1
    private const val HEADER_ID = 777
}

private val items = mutableListOf<TodoItem>()
private val headers = mutableListOf<TodoItem>()

init {
    items.addAll(data)

    headers.add(TodoItem(HEADER_ID, "приоритет: ${items[0].priority}", items[0].priority))

    items.map {
        if (it.priority != headers.last().priority) {
            headers.add(TodoItem(HEADER_ID, "приоритет: ${it.priority}", it.priority))
        }
    }
    items.addAll(headers)
    items.sortBy { it.priority }
    items.reverse()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return when (viewType) {
        TYPE_ITEM -> {
            ItemViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_todo, parent, false)
            )
        }
        TYPE_HEADER -> {
            HeaderViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_todo, parent, false)
            )
        }
        else -> ItemViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_todo, parent, false)
        )
    }
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]
    when (holder) {
        is ItemViewHolder -> {
            holder.title.text = item.title
            holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
                if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) dragListener(holder)
                false
            }
        }
        is HeaderViewHolder -> {
            holder.title.text = item.title
            holder.itemView.background = getDrawable(holder.itemView.context, R.color.teal_200)
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount() = items.size

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return if (items[position].id == HEADER_ID) TYPE_HEADER else TYPE_ITEM
}

inner class ItemViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val title: TextView = itemView.todo_title
}

inner class HeaderViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val title: TextView = itemView.todo_title
}

override fun onRowMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
    if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
        for (i in fromPosition until toPosition) {
            Collections.swap(items, i, i + 1)
        }
    } else {
        for (i in fromPosition downTo toPosition + 1) {
            Collections.swap(items, i, i - 1)
        }
    }
    changePositionListener(items[fromPosition])
    notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition)
}

override fun onRowSelected(myViewHolder: ItemViewHolder?) {
    myViewHolder?.itemView?.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
}

override fun onRowClear(myViewHolder: ItemViewHolder?) {
    myViewHolder?.itemView?.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
}
}
```

`ViewModel`:

```
class TodoSortViewModel : ViewModel() {

val items = MutableLiveData<MutableList<TodoItem>>().apply {
    value = mutableListOf(
        TodoItem(1, "Один", 0),
        TodoItem(2, "Два", 0),
        TodoItem(3, "Три", 0),
        TodoItem(4, "Четыре", 0),
        TodoItem(5, "Пять", 1),
        TodoItem(6, "Шесть", 1),
        TodoItem(7, "Семь", 1)
    )
}
}
```

`TodoItem`:

```
data class TodoItem(
val id: Int,
val title: String,
val priority: Int
)
```

`ItemMoveCallback`:

```
class ItemMoveCallback(private val contract: ItemTouchHelperContract) : ItemTouchHelper.Callback() {

override fun isLongPressDragEnabled(): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun isItemViewSwipeEnabled(): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, i: Int) {}

override fun getMovementFlags(
    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
): Int {
    val dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN
    return makeMovementFlags(dragFlags, 0)
}

override fun onMove(
    recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
): Boolean {
    contract.onRowMoved(viewHolder.adapterPosition, target.adapterPosition)
    return true
}

override fun onSelectedChanged(
    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?,
    actionState: Int
) {
    if (actionState != ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE) {
        if (viewHolder is RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder) {
            val myViewHolder: RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder? = viewHolder
            contract.onRowSelected(myViewHolder)
        }
    }
    super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState)
}

override fun clearView(
    recyclerView: RecyclerView,
    viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
) {
    super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder)
    if (viewHolder is RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder) {
        val myViewHolder: RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder = viewHolder
        contract.onRowClear(myViewHolder)
    }
}

interface ItemTouchHelperContract {
    fun onRowMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int)
    fun onRowSelected(myViewHolder: RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder?)
    fun onRowClear(myViewHolder: RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemViewHolder?)
}
}
```